# unable to rebind click event after doing unbind

Tags: jquery

I am facing issue while rebinding click event to a div. I have tried to achieve this with many things: 
1. on/off 
2. bind/unbind 
3. enable/disable div 
But nothing is working. Below is my current code:

```
$("#divid").click(function() {
    someMethod();
});

function someMethod(){
//code goes here
$("#divid").unbind('click');
}

//inside other method, i am trying to rebind the click event
function otherMethod(){
$('#divid').on("click", someMethod());
//Also tried
//$('#divid').on("click", someMethod);
}
```

I am getting error at Firefox console:
ReferenceError: someMethod is not defined 

i look into .on Api and on(event, handler_method_name) is valid

Please advice possible solutions.

Comment: I think the scopes in which the functions are executing are different

Comment: make sure the `someMethod` is defined in a scope which is accessible from `otherMethod`

Comment: also `$('#divid').on("click", someMethod());` is wrong, it should be `$('#divid').on("click", someMethod);`

Comment: I hope the divs are all display:block and not hidden.

Comment: he also tried that one also right

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zU5sj/

Comment: Can you provide a small fiddle or jsbin of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
function someMethod(){
//Do stuff here
});

$(document).off('click', '#divid').on('click', '#divid', someMethod);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the function with

```
   $('#divid').on("click", someMethod());
```

It should be

```
   $('#divid').on("click", function(){someMethod()});
```

Also I have called unbind before binding to avoid multiple bindings.
Check this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/m5yP7/1/